# List function to perform multiple calculations in r

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I recently began using R, and am grateful to the SO community for helping me create over 100 tibbles (divided by minute) of data similar to the one below.

```r
time1      pid    mlat mlong   malt m_time 
1 23:57:00 2A     434. 8347. 0.140  m_2357
2 23:57:00 2D     433. 8353. 0.0702 m_2357
3 23:57:00 3D     433. 8349. 0.0135 m_2357
4 23:57:00 4A     434. 8364. 0.147  m_2357
5 23:57:00 4B     433. 8351. 0.162  m_2357
```

The function below delivers a solution for single dataset.

```r
pd<- function(mtime){
dm <- data.frame(x=mtime$mlat, #dm = distance matrix
            y=mtime$mlong, 
            z=mtime$malt, 
            row.names= mtime$pid)
ed<- dist(dm) #em = euclidean distance
em <- as.matrix(ed) #em = euclidean matrix
em <- melt(em)[melt(upper.tri(em))$value,] 
names(em)<- c("pid","intercept", "distance") 
e_df <- as.data.frame(em)
e_df$distance <- round((e_df$distance/.0005399565), digits = 0)
e_df<- arrange(e_df,distance)
write.csv(e_df,"m_2357.csv")
}
pd(m_2357)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

After creating and imbedding the tibbles into a list (using m_time), the closest I have come to solving this problem is:

```r
mylist2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x){
  dm <- data.frame(x=mylist[[i]][["mlat"]],
                   y=mylist[[i]][["mlong"]], 
                   z=mylist[[i]][["malt"]], 
                   row.names= mylist[[i]][["pid”]]) …
```

This duplicates one correct solution 180 times so I think I am close (i is also stored as a value in my environment could that be a problem?). Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any examples of functions doing multiple calculations for a list. After I spent most of a day playing with combinations, I decided to ask for help.

My question is: After I get the data into a list, how do I write an lapply function for each tibble in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to extend existing function code. Simply run your list of data frames/tibbles directly into your function with `lapply` such as: `output <- lapply(mylist, pd)`.

However, your function as of now outputs a single hard-coded CSV named `"m_2357.csv"`. So all iterations will replace this file, leaving last run results in this ***single*** file. Therefore, you need to make the file name dynamic which appears to be your *m_time* column. Also, consider returning data frame and not result of `write.csv` which is usually `NULL`.

```
pd <- function(mtime){
  dm <- data.frame(x=mtime$mlat,
                   y=mtime$mlong, 
                   z=mtime$malt, 
                   row.names= mtime$pid)
  ...

  # DYNAMIC VARIABLE NAME
  write.csv(e_df, paste(mtime$m_time[1], ".csv")

  # RETURN ACTUAL DATA FRAME
  return(e_df)
}


new_df_list <- lapply(mylist, pd)
```

By the way, had your original setup been *one* large data frame/tibble with all 180 tibbles stacked together with the column *m_time* to distinguish between the sets, you could have run function with `by` (object-oriented wrapper of `tapply`), passing subsets by the column, *m_time*, into function:

```
new_df_list <- by(my_master_data_frame, my_master_data_frame$m_time, pd)
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I found your second answer most helpful because it cut down on the code and makes my project easier to read.

Comment: Fantastic! I have found `by` a very underutilized but useful method. Happy coding!